# maven publish jar to .ivy

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

I have a maven project, which will produce a jar file, and I want to use it in another sbt project. Is there any method to publish the jar file to .ivy rather than in .m2?

I try to put the jar file in the libs under the sbt project, but it does not work. and use the mvn install the jar to the .m2 does not work too.

Answer (score 18):

As I understand it you have a maven project and an SBT project. The SBT project depends on the artifact produced by your maven project.

You ask how to publish the maven produced artifact to your local .ivy so it can be picked up by the SBT project.

you can probably achieve that using an [ant task in the maven build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634590/publish-a-maven-artifact-to-a-local-ivy-repository-recursively-with-its-depende).

However I'd like to suggest different angles :

### Make the sbt project aware of the local .m2

Simply add `resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal` to your sbt build definition, if you don't want to *pollute* the main build definition, add that line to a `local.sbt` file alongside the main build defition. SBT merges all the `.sbt` files found at the project root.

### Publish to a controlled repository

This is especially useful if you want the build to be easily reproduceable outside of your local machine. 
The idea is simply to publish the maven project to an actual server, either an internal nexus/artifactory server for proprietary code or to a public artefact hosting (such as bintray) 
I use bintray all the time to publish custom builds of opensource projects while I wait for PRs to be merged in master and published an the official build.

Add your artifact server as a resolver to the SBT project and you are good to go :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. your suggestion is the way to solve my problem. Some times ago,I choose the first method at first, and this works, but I modify the maven project recently and publish it to the local m2 again, the sbt can not find it now, it try to find in public repos, this is very strange, since I changed nothing, so maybe I publish it to local .ivy2 can solve this. here is an issue in sbt : https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/321.

Comment: I will try the second method,  I just do not want to config a nexus server, it seem bintray is a good way. Thanks!

Comment: regarding the linked issue, have a look at this comment https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/321#issuecomment-159500317 it seems that the included mavelLocal shortcut may not work in recent SBT versions, and you need to define the .m2 repo manually (don't forget to accept the answer if it does solve your issue ... ;)

Comment: Thanks! In fact, I reply this comment under it, I use the absolute path at first, and tried the mavelLocal later too, but both of them not work.

Comment: in your comment on the github issue, you mention you are using 0.13.7 I very strongly advise upgrading to 0.13.9. I have found most plugins to work just fine but 0.13.8 and 0.13.9 have many important fixes ( memory leaks for tests, resolver stuff, etc) the issue itself is marked closed for milestone 0.13.8 ...

Comment: Thanks for your point out. I will try and see whether this will work.

Comment: One last thing, if for some reason your network restricts access to some repos you should look into a custom sbt.boot.properties http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Launcher-Configuration.html or force dns resolution to localhost in order to fail fast ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96266/discussion-between-djvu-and-jean).